# Data corruption after casting byte array to struct in C

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I have what should be a simple project I'm attempting to complete on two ARM Cortex Arduinos. I need to send data as a packed byte array over the air to a listening board on the other side. I'm using 2 `RFM69HCW` transceivers to send and receive the data. The library I'm using expects data of `uint8_t*` type -- alias of `char*` -- to send, and the same to receive. The same code using strings instead of structs works without issue, so it must be something in the way I'm converting to/from the struct. Here is my simplified example:

**TX.c**

```
/**
* TX.C
* Send a packed struct to a listening transceiver
*/
#include <RH_RF69.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define RFM69_CS 53
#define RFM69_INT 7
#define RFM69_RST 5

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) RP {
    double x, y, z;
    unsigned int time;
    uint8_t[4]   sound;
} RadioPacket;

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF69 rf69(RFM69_CS, RFM69_INT);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while(!Serial) delay(1);
    // setup failed. Cannot progress beyond this point
    if ( !(rf69.init() && rf69.setFrequency(915.0)) ) while(1) ;
}

void loop() {
  // only populate x,y,z currently. Other values are unknown
  RadioPacket radiopacket = RadioPacket { .x = 0.001, .y = 0.02, .z = 9.1 };
  // Send a message!
  rf69.send((uint8_t *)&radiopacket, sizeof(radiopacket));
  rf69.waitPacketSent();
  delay(100);
}
```

**RX.C**

```
/**
* TX.C
* Receive a byte array and transform it to a struct
*/

#include <RH_RF69.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define RFM69_CS 53
#define RFM69_INT 7
#define RFM69_RST 5

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) RP {
    double x, y, z;
    unsigned int time;
    uint8_t[4]   sound;
} RadioPacket;

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF69 rf69(RFM69_CS, RFM69_INT);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while(!Serial) delay(1);
    // setup failed. Cannot progress beyond this point
    if ( !(rf69.init() && rf69.setFrequency(915.0)) ) while(1) ;
}

void loop() {
  if (rf69.available()) {
    // Should be a message for us now   
    uint8_t buf[60];
    uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
    if (rf69.recv(buf, &len)) {
      if (!len) return;
      buf[len] = 0;
      // size of packet
      if(len == 32) {
        RadioPacket packet;
        // populate packet
        memcpy((void *)&packet, &buf, sizeof(RadioPacket));
        Serial.println(packet.x); // ovf
        Serial.println(packet.y); // 2.01
        Serial.println(packet.z); // 1.11
      }
}
```

Instead of the values I sent, I get completely different values after conversion. I've also tried straight casting without memcpy to save memory, but it's the same result.

Comment: Shouldn't `uint8_t[4] sound;` be `uint8_t sound[4];`?

Comment: IIRC, Arm chips are very fussy about correct alignment of `double` types. Your structure (with the correction suggested above) *looks* like it will be OK (but check that its size is what you think) assuming `int` is 4 bytes.  But maybe there are weird padding and/or aliasing issues, here.

Comment: richbai90,  "instead of the values I sent, I get completely different values after conversion." --> Post the data sent and data received - preferable as a hex dump.

Comment: @SupportUkraine As that is actually C++ there are overloaded functions `println`. Any data type is allowed according to that [spec](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println/)

Comment: `&buf` This should be `buf` as an array already decays to a pointer.